# Multiple Nexus Repository instances over the same S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nexus

I have Nexus Repository Manager v. 3.12 (OSS) set up on EC2 instance. I decided to place Nexus blobstore on S3 leveraging fuctionality that is built-in since 3.12. Everything works fine, when I have only one EC2 with Nexus running. If I try to set up another instance, also having ALB load-balance the traffic, things aren't going that well. When I upload an artifact through ALB address, it is visible only on one machine, the other is missing that artifact even after trying to rebuild the index. I suppose I'm missing some configuration in order to set up highly available cluster of Nexus instances backed by S3 store, but I cannot seem to find much info and I don't know if it is really possible to reuse the same store between instances. Has somebody already tried such setup and can guide me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In case you didn't know, HA is a PRO available feature of NXRM.  You said OSS so I assume you're trying to implement it somehow despite this.  I can assure you that 2 NXRM instances cannot share a blobstore however.  That will lead to DB corruption.  That is why HA is a distinct service in Nexus.  Doesn't answer your Q so commenting but FYI.

Comment: If it is in PRO version, then I suppose they aren't allowing this in OSS anyhow. Thanks for the explanation.